# jQuery Date returns wrong values?

Tags: java, jquery

I have a date picker that returns it value as `Mandag, 03/05/2021` today is 3rd May 2021. Now i passed it to date function

```
var pickedDate_n = new Date(pickedDate);
console.log(pickedDate_n);
```

And it returns
Fri Mar 05 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

```
var pickedDate_ch = (pickedDate_n.getDate()) + "/" + (pickedDate_n.getMonth()) +  "/" + pickedDate_n.getFullYear();
      console.log(pickedDate_ch);
```

Now that returns, which is totally wrong

```
5/2/2021
```

Comment: The getMonth() method returns the month from 0 to 11. So 2 will be March. If you want it "correct" use `(pickedDate_n.getMonth() + 1)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thank you but the getDate is 2 days ahead?

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla Both dates have a day of `5`. How is the date 2 days ahead?

Comment: @MarkBaijens what is pass in today that is 3 and it is returning current day as 5?

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla In javascript date format is "MM/dd/yyyy" could you check the date format. which you are assigned to pickedDate.

Comment: @komalkosbatwar ah I passed in Mandag, 03/05/2021. Wont it work?

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla Please check this Format "05/03/2021"

Comment: @komalkosbatwar that works . thanks but the date picker the format in recieve is 'DD, dd/mm/yy', is there a way to convert?

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla     Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript date format is `"MM/dd/yyyy"` could you check the date format. which you are assigned to pickedDate.

use this for change the date format to datepicker:

`var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yyyy' }).val();`

Answer (score 0):

The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.

Comment: Thank you. But still, the date is wrong? I am passing in 3rd and 5th is being returned?